# NodeJS WS Server failing to parse JSON data from C# WS client

Tags: c#, node.js, json, websocket

I'm trying to setup a web socket system in Unity that connects to a NodeJS backend, the problem I'm facing is that every time I send JSON to the node backend it crashes and fails to parse the data.
I've tried many things that I found online and other stack overflow questions but nothing is working.
When I console log `JSON.parse(data)` I get this: `{"type": "Buffer", "data": [123, 111, 112,58,32,49,125]}` but if I try to use `JSON.parse(data.toString())` or `JSON.parse(data)` or even `JSON.parse(data.buffer) // the web socket data is an ArrayBuffer from my understanding` the process crashes and says `Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`.
There was another thing I tried with character codes (Don't have the exactly code I used) and it printed [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y78cD.png) with strange ASCII or Unicode characters in the beginning. It seems to work fine when I send JSON to the c# client but not when sending a byte[] to the server. I've been trying to find a solution to this for almost an entire day now and I'm not sure what else to do.

I'm using NativeWebSocket on the c# client (https://github.com/endel/NativeWebSocket).

NodeJS Server Code:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const { createServer } = require("http");
const WebSocket = require("ws");

const app = express();

const server = createServer(app);
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });

wss.on("connection", function (ws) {
  console.log("client joined.");

  // send "hello world" every 1 second.
  var id = setInterval(() => ws.send("hello world!"), 100);

  ws.on("message", function (data) {
    if (typeof data !== "string") {
      console.log(JSON.parse(data.buffer));
    }
  });

  ws.on("close", function () {
    console.log("client left.");
    clearInterval(id);
  });
});

server.listen(8080, function () {
  console.log("Listening on http://localhost:8080");
});
```

C# Client Code:

```
async void Start()
{
    websocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080");

    websocket.OnOpen += () =>
    {
        Debug.Log("Connection open!");
    };

    websocket.OnError += (e) =>
    {
        Debug.Log("Error! " + e);
    };

    websocket.OnClose += (e) =>
    {
        Debug.Log("Connection closed!");
    };

    websocket.OnMessage += (bytes) =>
    {
        // Reading a plain text message
        var message = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
        Debug.Log("OnMessage! " + message);
    };

    // Keep sending messages at every 0.3s
    InvokeRepeating("SendWebSocketMessage", 0.0f, 0.3f);

    await websocket.Connect();
}

async void SendWebSocketMessage()
{
    if (websocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
    {
        // Sending bytes
        await websocket.Send(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{op: 1}"));

        // Sending plain text
        //await websocket.Send("{op: 1}");
    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking that the strange characters that appear before it in the one image is possibly the opcode and length. If thats the case I still don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

`"{op: 1}"` is not valid JSON string. Try `"{\"op\": 1}"`.

Comment: shi*, I didn't even realize that. Thank you!